# Why does jQuery not seem to add text to nested spans?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have tried this in a couple of different orders, and neither works. I start off like this:

```
var messageHtml = "<span class='message-bundle' id='" + randomId + "'></span>";
$(".visualizer").append(messageHtml);
```

`randomId` is a random number. Then I set the `top` and `left` positioning for the element (it is set to `position: absolute`).

Then I `.append()` the following empty `span`s to this `span`:

```
$(".message-bundle#" + randomId).append("<span class='usertag' id='" + randomId + "'></span><br/>" + 
                                        "<span class='message' id='" + randomId + "'></span>");
```

I keep them empty initially because I want to sanitize their contents against XSS exploits. **So far, everything is fine.** Then I add sanitized text to these nested spans.

```
$(".message-bundle .usertag#" + randomId).text(msgObj.usertag);
$(".message-bundle .message#" + randomId).text(msgObj.message);
```

This never works. I have tried printing out the `.text()` of these two elements, but they contain empty strings. Why is this? Can I somehow sanitize the strings and add them inline when creating the `.usertag` and `.message` spans above (instead of using `.text()`)?

Comment: The problem is the `#` you're putting after `.messagebundle`.

Comment: @Barmar: No it isn't - look at the whole expression: `".message-bundle#" + randomId`

Comment: I misread the code, I thought `randomId` was part of the class.

Comment: Are each `randomId` at `$(".message-bundle .usertag#" + randomId).text(msgObj.usertag);
$(".message-bundle .message#" + randomId).text(msgObj.message);` the same `id` ?

Comment: Since it's a single expression, they must be the same.

Comment: @Barmar _"randomId is a random number"_ Though how generated not appear at OP ? If same , would lead to duplicate `id`'s ? If `randomId` a function , could return different values ?

Comment: If it's a function it would have to have `()` after it.

Comment: @Barmar http://jsfiddle.net/y7ukxknb/ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`id`s need to be unique throughout the entire document, and you’re duplicating them. It’s an inappropriate use of them anyway, though; you should work with elements more and HTML less.

```
var message =
    $('<span>', { class: 'message-bundle' })
        .append($('<span>', { class: 'usertag', text: msgObj.usertag }))
        .append($('<span>', { class: 'message', text: msgObj.message }));

$('.visualizer').append(message);
```

This appends elements that you can manipulate as proper objects from the moment they’re created, rather than by re-selecting them after adding HTML.

Answer (score 1):

IDs must be unique within the document - you're assigning the same ID to multiple elements.  (Or is that just over-simplified code?)

Comment: He's assigning a different `randomId` to each one.

Comment: @Barmar: The `randomId` is duplicated between `.message-bundle`, `.usertag`, and `.message`.